# Netty and ByteOrder

Tags: netty, endianness

Due to poor documentation and lack of experience with Netty, i faced with little problem.
I have no clue how can i set a default ByteOrder.

I need a **Little-Endian** set by default.
I'll be glad, if someone will give me some hints about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Bootstrap.setOption()` to do this.

```
    serverBootstrap.setOption("child.bufferFactory", new
HeapChannelBufferFactory(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN));
    ... or ...
    clientBootstrap.setOption("bufferFactory", new
HeapChannelBufferFactory(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN));
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint Abe. I saw this in api, but doubted.
Gonna try that.

Comment: How to do that in Netty 4.x or Netty 5.x?