# netty 4: set default endianness of ByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

Is there a way to tell Netty 4 that all `ByteBuf` instances it creates should have LITTLE_ENDIAN endianness?

Calling [order(ByteOrder)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) in every handler is annoying.

It looks like Netty 3 supported this: [Netty and ByteOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758537/netty-and-byteorder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expect one: big-endian is the ordering of network protocols, so makes sense as the default. And exposing a static variable to set the default would be an invitation for hard-to-diagnose bugs (particularly in a shared server).

I think your best approach is to create a new factory class, to produce the buffers you need. Assuming that you're currently using `Unpooled` (per recommendation), it should be a simple search-and replace operation.

You could also update `Unpooled` itself, providing variants that take a byte-order param, and submit it back to the project.

Comment: I changed my original post to add a reference to a way to do it in Netty 3. BTW: I do have an existing network protocol with a working NIO impl server-side. I just want to replace that with Netty.